How to extract and insert json data in a key and value format
I have this data and would like to extract the Title data only and insert it as a id and value.
const dataSource = [
{
id: '1',
Title: 'My World',
Price: 10,
},
{
id: '2',
Title: 'My Home',
Price: 20,
},
{
id: '3',
Title: 'My Kitchen',
Price: 30,
},
{
id: '4',
Title: 'My Garden',
Price: 40,
},
{
id: '5',
Title: 'My Furniture',
Price: 50,
},
];
I am expecting to get something like this:
const myData = [
{
id: 'My World',
value: 'My World',
},
{
id: 'My Home',
value: 'My Home',
},
{
id: 'My Kitchen',
value: 'My Kitchen',
},
{
id: 'My Garden',
value: 'My Garden',
},
{
id: 'My Furniture',
value: 'My Furniture',
},
];

Are you just looking for the .map() function for arrays?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

You can use map
const data = dataSource.map(item => ({
  id: item.Title,
  value: item.Title
}));

console.log(data);

